# Discrete optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to decide on the best approach for my problem, which is as follows:

I have a set of objects (about 3k-5k) which I want to uniquely assign to about 10 groups (1 group per object).
Each object has a set of grades corresponding with how well it fits within each group.
Each group has a capacity of objects it can manage (the constraints).
My goal is to maximize the sum of grades my assignments receive.

For example, let's say I have 3 objects (o1, o2, o3) and 2 groups (g1,g2) with a cap. of 1 object each.
Now assume the grades are:

**o1:** g1=11, g2=8

**o2:** g1=10, g2=5

**o3:** g1=5, g2=6

In that case, for the optimal result g1 should receive o2, and g2 should receive o1, yielding a total of 10+8=18 points.

Note that the number of objects can either exceed the sum of quotas (e.g. leaving o3 as a "leftover") or fall short from filling the quotas.

How should I address this problem (Traveling Salesman, sort of a weighted Knap-Sack etc.)? How long should brute-forcing it take on a regular computer? Are there any standard tools such as the linprog function in Matlab that support this sort of problem?

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved with min cost flow algorithm.
The graph can look the following way:

It should be bipartite. The left part represents objects(one vertex for each object). The right part represents groups(one vertex for each group). There is an edge from each vertex from the left part to each vertex from the right part with `capacity` = 1 and `cost` = -grade for this pair. There is also an edge from the source vertex to each vertex from the left part with `capacity` = 1 and `cost` = 0 and there is an edge from each vertex from the right part to the sink vertex(sink and source are two additional vertices) with `capacity` = constraints for this group and `cost` = 0.

The answer is `-the cheapest flow cost from the source to the sink`.

It is possible to implement it with `O(N^2 * M * log(N + M))` time complexity(using Dijkstra algorithm with potentials)(`N` is the  number of objects, `M` is the number of groups).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with an integer program. Binary variables x_{ij} state if object i is assigned to group j. The objective maximized \sum_{i,j} s_{ij}x_{ij}, where s_{ij} is the score associated with assigning i to j and x_{ij} is whether i is assigned to j. You have two types of constraints:

- \sum_i x_{ij} <= c_j for all j, the capacity constraints for groups
- \sum_j x_{ij} <= 1 for all i, limiting objects to be assigned to at most one group

Here's how you would implement it in R -- the `lp` function in R is quite similar to the `linprog` function in matlab.

```
# Score matrix
S <- matrix(c(11, 10, 5, 8, 5, 6), nrow=3)
# Capacity vector
cvec <- c(1, 1)

# Helper function to construct constraint matrices
unit.vec <- function(pos, n) {
  ret <- rep(0, n)
  ret[pos] <- 1
  ret
}

# Capacity constraints
cap <- t(sapply(1:ncol(S), function(j) rep(unit.vec(j, ncol(S)), nrow(S))))

# Object assignment constraints
obj <- t(sapply(1:nrow(S), function(i) rep(unit.vec(i, nrow(S)), each=ncol(S))))

# Solve the LP
res <- lp(direction="max",
          objective.in=as.vector(t(S)),
          const.mat=rbind(cap, obj),
          const.dir="<=",
          const.rhs=c(cvec, rep(1, nrow(S))),
          all.bin=TRUE)

# Grab assignments and objective
sln <- t(matrix(res$solution, nrow=ncol(S)))
apply(sln, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(x) > 0.999, which(x == 1), NA))
# [1]  2  1 NA
res$objval
# [1] 18
```

Although this is modeled with binary variables, it will solve quite efficiently assuming integral capacities.